# Use a metaclass only for subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Is there a way in *Python 3.2* or later to define a class whose subclasses should be created using a specific metaclass without the class itself being created using that metaclass?

An example to demonstrate what I mean: Let's say I want to create an `Enum` class whose subclasses can be used to define enum types. An enum type would have a fixed number of instances, each of which has a distinct `int` (or other) value. An enum type would be declared by creating a subclass of `Enum` and assigning the values to attributes of that class. Through the metaclass of `Enum`, the values of those attributes would be replace by instances of the new class.

The `Enum` class may also define some class or instance methods or members that can be used on its subclasses or their instances.

```
class EnumMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, what, bases, dict):
        cls = super().__new__(mcs, what, bases, { })

        cls._instances_by_value = { }

        for k, v in dict.items():
            if k.startswith('__') or k == 'get_by_value':
                setattr(cls, k, v)
            else:
                instance = cls(k, v)

                setattr(cls, k, instance)
                cls._instances_by_value[v] = instance

        return cls


class Enum(metaclass = EnumMeta):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}.{}'.format(type(self).__name__, self.name)

    @classmethod
    def get_by_value(cls, value):
        return cls._instances_by_value[value]
```

An example for creating such an enum type:

```
class Boolean(Enum):
    true = 0
    false = 1
    file_not_found = 2

print(Boolean.true) # Prints Boolean.true
print(Boolean.get_by_value(1)) # Prints Boolean.false
```

In the definition of `EnumMeta.__new__`, you can see that I had to exclude `get_by_value` from the processing of the metaclass. I often run into this problem when I want to process the members of a class definition in some way using a metaclass.

What is the preferred approach to exclude the base class (`Enum` in the example) from processing by the metaclass (`EnumMeta` in the example) while using the metaclass for all subclasses of the base class?

I don't think that excluding all members of the base class while processing the members of a subclass is the preferred approach. I don't care about the value of `type(Enum)`. It can either be `EnumMeta` or `type`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your 'parent' `Enum` won't have any bases, only classes derived from `Enum` will have a non-empty `bases` tuple. Use this to easily bail out early to create the base class with a regular `__new__` call:

```
class EnumMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, what, bases, dict):
        if not bases:
            # Enum itself
            return super().__new__(mcs, what, bases, dict)

        # Process subclass creation
```

Comment: This is indeed a very clean solution. How would you handle the case where `Enum` _does_ have base classes? Check for an exact match of the `bases` dict?

Comment: Yes, checking for an exact match would work too. That's what we are doing here, after all.